# GL Error value 1285: Out of memory

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to render a simple quad in a few different ways.

I can do this very easily when everything is stored in one class.  But I want to be able to render more than a single object on the screen so I'm starting to take the code apart and put various bits of functionality in separate classes.  The problem is, when I put the rendering functionality in the Entity class, I start getting an error.

This is the function, which is is a VertexArrayObject class:

```
public void render(){
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiID);

    this.exitOnGLError("Before render");
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    this.exitOnGLError("After render");

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    this.exitOnGLError("error rendering vao");
}
```

Again, all I have done is move this from the main class into a class that manages the VAO and theoretically renders it.

It's giving me error value 1285, and the error call that gets the error is the one labeled "After render".  (exitOnGLError() is an error checking method).

Error 1285 apparently means "Out of memory" which is patently absurd since I'm using a 1 megabyte image file and...I just can't imagine my four vertex float buffer is filling up all my VRAM.

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: What is the value of indicesCount at the time the error occurs? When does the error happen? Is it just after you launch the application, or after a few seconds?

Comment: What could be causing this is that you're somewhere often allocating large chunks of memory without deleting anything (a memory leak). It's not possible to see from your code what the actual reason is, though.

Comment: indicesCount = 6.  There are only six unsigned bytes in the element buffer.  The window opens and closes and never actually renders the first frame.  I wouldn't even know which code to show you to find the memory leak.  The only things that are sent to the graphics card are the shader program, a VAO/VBO pair, and a 2048*2048 pixel texture.  It is unfathomable to me that that small amount of data could be generating a memory leak sufficient to overload my graphics card.  I don't think it's a memory leak.  I think there's something else happening.

Comment: hm. Did you actually create an openGL context? What calls did you use to create your scene? The items themselves should indeed not stuff up the VRAM. Though be aware that 2048x2048 is the maximum texture size according to the openGL standard. If it closes instantly there's indeed no memory leak.

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to look into some of what you're saying here.  I might not be able to get back to you right away.

Comment: Basically, what openGL functions do you call after the initial LWJGL Display.(...) calls before you start pumping out frames? OpenGL needs you to call a few functions before you can start doing so. Small correction: the max texture size is more in the order of 4096x4096.

Comment: Why are you enabling and disabling attribute arrays when you're using a VAO? VAOs store all of the vertex state needed to render.

Comment: you need to bind at least one VBO to a VAO... maybe this is the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI I had this same error, and it was caused by the fact that I failed to add the call to glBufferData, which is where you actually "send the data" to opengl.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLSL_XYZNDUV_Item)*p->iNum_verts,p->pVerts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*p->iNum_tris*2,p->pIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a possible answer for those coming here from Google.

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( indices ), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Note the copypaste error in bold.  This caused error 1285 and quite a bit of head scratching for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You should first verify that you make all OpenGL class in the correct order, e.g. you should only bind the VBOs when creating the VAO, not when rendering it.

Here's how I order the calls in my VAO class:

```
    // creation
    array = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(array);

    vertices = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b, usage);

    for (attributes) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(index);
        glVertexAttribPointer(index, dimension, type, false, bytesPerVertex, offset);
    }

    if (indices are used) {
      indices = glGenBuffers();
      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);
      glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, usage);
    }

    // render
    glBindVertexArray(array);
    program.use(); // binds shader program and textures
    if (indices == -1)
        glDrawArrays(mode, 0, size);
    else
        glDrawElements(mode, size, indicesType, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just run into the same error when rendering a `.obj` file with OpenGL on Android 11 (works fine on Android 9).
There seems to be a bug in OpenGL making it throw the out of memory error whenever the source vertices in the `.obj` file are defined in the [Vertex normal indices without texture coordinate indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) format (`f 113//113 76//76 77//77`). To circumvent the error, just add a single texture coordinate to the file (e.g. `vt 0.500 1`) and reference it in every single face (turn `f 113//113 76//76 77//77` into `f 113/1/113 76/1/76 77/1/77`)